# CSS Separate Date Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I just started front end development and I wonder how can I achieve something like this on the date section of the form?

[image: Fig 1.0]

Is it just regular `<select>` tag? Or can I customize the `<input type="date">` using CSS?

Comment: Three selectbox. I suggest to use pikaday datepicker rather than 3 selectbox.

Comment: You could use a date input but it looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ob4g71ha/). The example above is three selects.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So if I am going to use <select>, should I use javascript to validate the number of days to its corresponding month and year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `<select>` tag and JS in validating the days and year.

Reference: [Dynamic Date Select (Php/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316592/dynamic-date-select-php-js)

Answer (score 1):

in that particular instance they look like three `<select>` boxes styled to sit side by side

when using `<input type="date" />` this appears as a date with a calendar icon (depending on browser) which will produce a calendar pop-up

Answer (score 0):

`type='date'` will always show you input box with the label `mm/dd/yyyy`

These are 3 seperate `select` boxes.

you can customize date, for that you need to modify its whole specifiers and events aswell.